# how to change the flow items order in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

by default, on a UICollectionView with flow layout and horizontal direction, cells are ordered from top to bottom, left to right. Like this:

```
1 3 5 7  9 11
2 4 6 8 10 12
```

In my case, the collection view is paged and it has been designed so that a specific number of cells fits in each page. Thus, a more natural ordering would be:

```
1 2 3    7  8  9
4 5 6 - 10 11 12
```

i need to have the same items order of vertical flow but with horizontal direction

how can I achieve this? 
thank's in advance

Comment: I think you need to use another custom layout. Flow layout works this way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Implement UICollectionView and create custom collection view cell, which contains 6 labels in a way ---

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Set number of items in collection view :-

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return array.count;
}
```

Set number of sections :-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Set layout size at index path as per your requirement

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // set size of collection view cell (width, height)
    return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width)-40, 200);
}
```

Collection view data ai different index path. Make IBOutlet of labels in CustomCollectionViewCell class and connect into storyboard :-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCollectionViewCell* customCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"waitingRoomTipId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // set data as per the requirement 
    customCell.label1.text = @"Label1";
    customCell.label2.text = @"Label2";
    customCell.label3.text = @"Label3";
    customCell.label4.text = @"Label4";
    customCell.label5.text = @"Label5";
    customCell.label6.text = @"Label6";

    return customCell;
}
```

This is how six labels will be displayed in every cell.

Hope this solution will help you.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use UICollectionView's `moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath:` to do that.

It has source and destination Indexpath values.Just Drag and Drop user Collection view Cell where ever you Required.